# empty value cell if the value cell in previous row is the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the query:

```
select RankCode, (SELECT '' + SUBSTRING( CONVERT(VARCHAR, FromDate, 120) ,11, 6) + ' -' + SUBSTRING( CONVERT(VARCHAR, ToDate, 120), 11, 6) ) as WorkingHoursAtSea
from WorkingHoursSchedule
where SeaPortInd = 0 and watchkeepingind = 0
```

And this is the result table from the above :

```
+----------+-------------------+
| RankCode | WorkingHoursAtSea |
+----------+-------------------+
| C/E      |  05:00 - 07:00    |
| C/E      |  01:00 - 02:00    |
| MSTR     |  00:30 - 02:30    |
+----------+-------------------+
```

I want to take the following table:

```
+----------+-------------------+
| RankCode | WorkingHoursAtSea |
+----------+-------------------+
| C/E      |  05:00 - 07:00    |
|          |  01:00 - 02:00    |
| MSTR     |  00:30 - 02:30    |
+----------+-------------------+
```

I use MS SQL SERVER 2014.

Comment: please post expected result and current result as text

Comment: If you are on last versions, use `lag`

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

First, your query does not require a nested `SELECT`.  And, in SQL Server, you should *always* include length with character type definitions (the default varies by context and may not be large enough).  So:

```
select RankCode,
      (substring(convert(varchar(255), FromDate, 120), 11, 6) + ' -' + 
       substring(convert(varchar(255), ToDate, 120), 11, 6)
      ) as WorkingHoursAtSea 
from WorkingHoursSchedule 
where SeaPortInd = 0 and watchkeepingind = 0 ;
```

(The "255" is arbitrary and just intended to be big enough.)

Next, you have another problem because SQL tables and results sets are inherently *unordered*.  You need a column to specify the ordering and your query has no `order by`.  When you decide what the column is, you can use `lag()` or `row_number()` to get the information you want:

```
select RankCode,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by RankCode order by ??) = 1
             then (substring(convert(varchar(255), FromDate, 120), 11, 6) + ' -' + 
                   substring(convert(varchar(255), ToDate, 120), 11, 6)
                  )
        end) as WorkingHoursAtSea 
from WorkingHoursSchedule 
where SeaPortInd = 0 and watchkeepingind = 0 ;
```

EDIT:

Oh, you should really do that type of processing in the application layer.  You can do this in SQL, but an `ORDER BY` is imperative, because result sets are unordered . . . and ordering is important for your results.

Here is the idea:

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by RankCode order by ??) = 1
             then RankCode
        end) as RankCode,
      (substring(convert(varchar(255), FromDate, 120), 11, 6) + ' -' + 
       substring(convert(varchar(255), ToDate, 120), 11, 6)
      ) as WorkingHoursAtSea 
from WorkingHoursSchedule 
where SeaPortInd = 0 and watchkeepingind = 0
order by RankCode, ??;
```

The `??` should be the same.  You can try `FromDate desc` in both cases to get the output in the question.

Comment: Can you please look at my desired table to explain me more? I don't know how row number() works...Thanks you very much!

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Excellent detailed explanation

Comment: @GordonLinoff Your solution does not have an `ORDER BY` so there is no SQL guarantee that the rows without the NULLs will appear before those with the NULLs.  Because of how the optimiser will sort the rows to calculate `ROW_NUMBER` it will display in the desired order in practice. Also I think you've blanked the wrong column?!? I very much agree with the elimination of the `SELECT` in the `WorkingHoursAtSea` column.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I believe it should be `order by WorkingHoursSchedule.RankCode, ??` to honour the partitioning first. It is also possible, although maybe not with this dataset, that with duplicate ??'s you could `row_number` one first and `order by` the other first. As you point out, doing the blanking the presentation layer would prevent most of these issues.

Comment: @Unoembre . . . Yes, the partitioning key should also be in the outer `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN row_number() OVER (
                PARTITION BY RankCode ORDER BY FromDate desc
                ) = 1
            THEN RankCode
        ELSE ''
        END AS RankCode
    ,substring(convert(VARCHAR(255), FromDate, 120), 11, 6) + ' -' + substring(convert(VARCHAR(255), ToDate, 120), 11, 6) AS WorkingHoursAtSea
FROM WorkingHoursSchedule
WHERE SeaPortInd = 0
    AND watchkeepingind = 0;
```

It is very similar to @Gordon Linoff post.

Comment: Thank you @StackUser!! I have one more question! It is possible to occur any incompatibilities with old versions of SQL server such as SQL SERVER 2005 with the above implementations? .